# Register on Magento bypassing validation

Tags: magento

One of my websites has gone through some testing for security.

Although this passed the security (as the code failed) I am curious in the methods.

The website has a couple of "new users" with attempted and failed SQL Injections.

Now the email is not a valid email address and we have a captcha on the form which appears to have been bypassed (as we believe it was a script)

Does anybody know of any places a user registration would take place which would bypass the usual controllers ( Mage_Customer_AccountController::createPostAction() )

Answer (score 0):

The only other way I know of for creating a customer would be [via the API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.create.html). I've never really worked with the core API, but at a quick glance I'm not sure that this actually calls validate on the customer model, so it seems a viable option.